# How do I store each date between 2 sets of dates in a separate column

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a table A like so:

```
id  |    valid_from_date    |      valid_to_date     |
 1  |  2015-05-01 23:15:01  |   2015-05-02 10:20:23  | 
 2  |  2015-07-13 10:25:02  |   2015-07-14 18:20:45  |
```

I want to be able to get all the dates between valid_from_date & valid_to_date per id, in the below format, which I then intend to put in a new table:

```
id  |   date     |
 1  | 2015-05-01 |
 1  | 2015-05-02 |
 2  | 2015-07-13 |
 2  | 2015-07-14 |
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it's best way or not....but it gives Required output....

create tableb as:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableb` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`dates` date DEFAULT NULL,
`aid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now,

```
insert into tableb(aid,dates) select id,date(valid_from_date) as dates
from tablea union select
id,date(valid_to_date) as dates  from tablea order by id;
```

May be Stored procedure is right option :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `test_procedure`()
BEGIN
DECLARE aid INT;
DECLARE avalid_from_date date;
DECLARE avalid_to_date date;
DECLARE tempdt date;
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE getdates CURSOR FOR SELECT * from tablea;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN getdates;

read_loop: LOOP
 FETCH getdates INTO aid,avalid_from_date,avalid_to_date;

    IF done THEN
  LEAVE read_loop;  
END IF;

set tempdt=date(avalid_from_date);

WHILE (tempdt <= date(avalid_to_date)) do
  insert into tableb(dates,aid) values( tempdt,aid);
  set tempdt=tempdt+INTERVAL 1 DAY;
end while;


 END LOOP;
 CLOSE getdates;
 END
```

Now,Just `call test_procedure;`
All the output rows will be inserted in tableb.

Comment: Hi Smita, thank you, but I'm not sure if completely understand your syntax. Could you please elaborate? Which is source table(A) and destination table(B)?

Comment: I understand your answer, but the problem is that id is not just a 'counter', it is a unique number that has relevance.  So for instance, table A will have id values such as '43225, 43223', so on and so forth. Thus, I will need to copy from Table A (each id value, and the associated dates for that id value) into Table B. Please advise.

Comment: ohh...so you want id also

Comment: Hi Smita, almost there. However there is a small issue. The above displays only the valid_from_date & the valid_to_date (per each id), it's not including the dates in-between e.g. if for id = 1, valid_from_date is 05/01/2015 and valid_to_date is 05/03/2015, it only displays 2 dates for id = 1 (05/01/2015 & 05/03/2015, it doesn't include 05/02/2015)

Comment: I think then stored procedure is the best option

Comment: well noted on this, I will test it out, thank you :)

Comment: The above worked, thank you! however I am having additional issues. Will post in a separate thread :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111211/discussion-between-smita-ahinave-and-logicpro).